# Change default slide-size on PowerPoint 2010

Tags: size, powerpoint, slide, page-setup

I use PowerPoint 2010 and need to create automatically PowerPoint (with excel VBA) with the slide size 16:9, so I would like to set this value as the default one (instead of 4:3). Could someone help me ? Or does someone maybe know how to choose this Slide-Size with excel VBA ?

Thanks for your help !

Charlotte

Comment: You can't change the default slide size, but you could change the slide size under program control after creating the new presentation.

Comment: thanks, I finally found how to create my presentation with this format with newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = PpSlideSizeType.ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9 :)